# Is it Haram to dislike listening to Quran in Tajweed

Tags: halal-haram, quran, quran-recitation

Is it haram to dislike the sound of someone reciting the Quran?

And if so, what about in the situations where:

#### The listener does **not** understand the Arabic language.

The listener may not understand the words, and the words at that point just become noise.

#### The listener understands and accepts the Quran entirely

Someone who enjoys to listen to the Quran being read normally, however feels the form of the Tajweed that many Imams employ is displeasing to the ear.

Comment: It is not possible to recite the Quran in English. The Quran is only in Arabic. Also, what does it mean he feels the "style" is displeasing? If the meaning is "tajweed," the tajweed of the Quran is passed down from the Prophet and Sahabah. In what sense can it be displeasing?

Comment: @TheZ I have updated my answer to remove the English to Arabic example, and placed the word tajweed where I previously used style/form. Displeasing in the sense that it is akin to someone trying to sing a story. When I read books on philosophy or virtue I do not say them in the style of Tajweed because that would be distracting. I have much more concentration on the words, when they are simply spoken. Surely if it benefits me and brings me closer to Gods meaning, it is therefore better for me as a whole.

Comment: Tajweed is part of the Quran itself. Do not compare the Quran to "books on philosophy or virtue." The Quran is not just a book like other books.The word "Quran" itself means "recitation."

Comment: @TheZ That may all be very well and true, however it doesn't distract from the main question and statement I made. Reading and understanding the message of the Quran is made easier for some when simply read, instead of pronounced in the form of the tajweed. Therefore, it leads us back to my original question, is it haram to think this way. If you have an answer, I would prefer it stated as such with proper ciations to the Quran or Sunnah. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These two sources do not answer the question of is disliking the tajweed in general haram. But they do shed some light for situations where you are listening to Tajweed involuntarily.

### 1.) A person is not blamed for being disturbed and harmed by someone who raises his voice when reciting the Quran.

I have found this answer on [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/236935/she-finds-the-voice-of-some-people-when-reciting-quran-irritating)

The heart of the Muslim should be attached to the verses that are being recited and not to the voice of the reciter and his/her performance. However, not liking the voice of the reciter, and not willing to listen to him is a matter of the heart which a person may not have control of. So, he is not to be blamed in this regard and he is not sinful.

It is for this reason that it is Islamically prohibited for the worshippers to disturb each other by raising their voice when reciting the Quran. Abu Sa‘eed Al-Khudri  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him said,

“The Messenger of Allaah  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) observed I‘tikaaf (i.e. seclusion for the purpose of worship) in the Masjid and heard worshippers reciting the Quran out loud. He opened the curtain and said:

> “Verily, each of you is in a private conversation with his Lord so you should not disturb each other. And you are not to raise your voices against each other in recitation.”

[Abu Daawood - Al-Albaani graded it Saheeh (sound)]

### 2.) In the situation of disturbance

I have found this answer on [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/236935/she-finds-the-voice-of-some-people-when-reciting-quran-irritating)

If the group does not want to listen because of being preoccupied by something else, and if they hear the voice of the reciter, it would probably disturb them or harm them, then, in this case, one should not raise his voice (while reciting);

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said:

> “If there are other people who are disturbed by his recitation, like a sleeping person or a person who is performing the prayer, and the like, then he should not raise his voice to an extent that disturbs them, because the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) came out to the people while some of them were praying while raising their voice with the recitation of the Quran, and he said: Indeed a person who is praying is calling upon his Lord, so he should concentrate on what he is calling with and you should not raise your voices over others while reciting the Quran.”

[Maalik in Al-Muwatta', and Ibn 'Abdul Barr said: It is a Saheeh (sound) Hadeeth]